# AWS Get Resources' Tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-sdk, aws-resource-group

I am trying to get different resources' (EC2s, DynamoDB tables, etc) certain tags by querying with resource ID or ARN in lambda functions. Is there a way to achieve this? I've created a resource group and I can see all resources with the tags I want there, but I can't access them from lambda (I don't just want to see the list of resources that belong to the resource group but also each resource's tags' key-value pairs).

I've created a resource group and I can see all resources with the tags I want there, but I can't access them from lambda functions. I want to see resources' tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Get Resources API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_GetResources.html).

Here's a sample snippet for a Lambda Python environment.
I've tested it with EC2 and RDS resources, but you can use it for any resource type you'd like.

```python
import json
import boto3
    
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = client.get_resources(
        TagFilters=[
            {
                'Key': 'tag-key',
                'Values': [
                   'tag-value',
                ]
            },
        ]
     )
     return response
```